# Finding the orbit of an element in $S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, group-actions

I'm confused on how to find the orbits of elements.

The orbit for $\sigma\in S_X $ is defined to be $O_{x,\sigma} = \{y\,|\,\sigma^n (x) = y\}$.

I need to compute the orbit of the permutation $\alpha = (1254)$.

I think the notation $\sigma^n (x)$ is confusing me more than anything else. Would the orbit just be the set $\{\sigma \alpha,\sigma^2 \alpha, \sigma^3 \alpha\, \sigma^4 \alpha, \alpha\}$?

Why or why not?

Can someone explain this for me?

Comment: That would make sense. But I'm still confused on how to find $\{\sigma^k(x)\}$

Comment: It is confusing indeed. Usually we define orbit of an element $x\in X$ to be a subset of $X$ -- assuming that the group has an action on $X$. Maybe some more context? Where did you read it

Comment: Abstract Algebra - Theory and Applications - Judson - Chapter 5, Exercise 32(c).

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. Here $\alpha$ has two orbits, $\{1,2,4,5\}$ and $\{3\}$. How does that sound?

Comment: Yes, that seems quite right. (But I would probably rather say "orbits of the cyclic group generated by $\alpha$")

Comment: @PeterFranek The action can be on the group itself

Comment: @Fakemistake Yes, just it was not very clear from the question.

Comment: @MathEntrepeneur100, I think you have given the right interpretation in your comment hereabove, not in the OP. Indeed, the cycle structure of a permutation $\sigma$ pops up naturally when considering the action -as a group of permutations- of the subgroup generated by $\sigma$, namely $\langle\sigma\rangle$. In your case, the permutation is a $4$-cycle, so its cycle structure as a permutation of $S_5$ is $(1,4)$.